# JDY-08 w/HM10 firmware won't change any parameters

Tags: stm32, uart, at-command, keil, hm-10

I have a custom circuit with STM32F030F4P6 as a main controller and HDY-08 flashed with HM-10 firmware as a Bluetooth LE transmitter.

What I wanted to do on circuit power on is to manually set the module up with custom parameters (name, baud, mode) and then proceed to the main calculating part.

However, what I noticed is that module won't act after any of the AT commands received, though it responds with OK+... strings.

For example, I send "AT+NAMEmyname" and receive "OK+Set:myname", however, the name doesn't change at all and remains HMSoft in Bluetooth scan on my phone.
Being on baudrate of 9600 I send "AT+BAUD4" and receive "OK+Set:4", then I send "AT+BAUD?" STILL on the baud of 9600 and receive the same: "OK+BAUD4" - the module keeps working on 9600, however, says it is on 115200. Tried playing with pulling reset and sys_key up and down for different time intervals, which results in nothing but not working AT commands.

Currently I have my module with RESET pin pulled up and SYS_KEY pulled up for 1200 milliseconds at start, then it is pulled down and then I proceed to send AT commands with delays of 250 milliseconds between Transmitting/Receiving sessions:

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SYSTEM_KEY_GPIO_Port, SYSTEM_KEY_Pin, 1);
HAL_Delay(1200);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SYSTEM_KEY_GPIO_Port, SYSTEM_KEY_Pin, 0);

HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*)setup, 8, 100);
HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, (uint8_t*)response, 8, 100);

HAL_Delay(250);

HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*)reset, 8, 100);
HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, (uint8_t*)response2, 8, 100);

HAL_Delay(250);

HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*)check, 8, 100);
HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, (uint8_t*)response3, 8, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved:
I don't know why, but after several times of dragging the same code here and there, I got the working solution:
RESET Pin 1
SYSTEM_KEY Pin 1
PWR 1

1. SYSTEM_KEY Pin 0
2. Delay 1200 millis
3. SYSTEM_KEY Pin 1
4. AT+BAUD4 -> OK+Set:4
5. Delay 250 millis
6. Reinitialize UART on STM, now with baudrate of 115200
7. AT+BAUD? -> OK+Get:4
8. It works, data flows as needed.

Thank you me for answering <3